# Как можно отправить xml данные и получить ответ с помощью SOAP+PHP?

Tags: php, xml, soap

Здравствуйте. С SOAP не работал, я чайник ((((. Помогите составить запрос.
Мне надо отправить xml Отправить данные

```
<S:Body><ns2:updateDataResponse><token>6cc1447c386b4a65b3b980eaf07f7f37f680ec4496b04f1ca2c51</token><tabcode>12345</tabcode><tabname> text</tabname></ns2:updateDataResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

Возвращает мне примерно такие параметры:

```
<S:Envelope><SOAP-ENV:Header/><S:Body><ns2:updateDataResponse><return><resultCode>0</resultCode><resultMessage>OK</resultMessage><serviceId>185</serviceId><timeStamp>1458118724461</timeStamp><vername>2.2</vername></return></ns2:updateDataResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

мне надо написать это в php, нашёл пример

/*сам xml который исправно отправляется с помощью того-же SOAPUI */

```
$query="`<S:Envelope>
 <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
 <S:Body>
 <ns2:updateDataResponse>
 <token>6cc1447c386b4a65b3b980eaf07f7f37f680ec4496b04f1ca2c51</token>
 <tabcode>kod</tabcode>
 <tabname>text</tabname>
 </ns2:updateDataResponse>
 </S:Body>
 </S:Envelope>
 </code>";
/*создаю клиента*/
$client =  new SoapClient ("адрес soap?wsdl", array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2)); 
/*Пытаюсь отправить запрос*/
$result = $client->getTicket($query);
var_dump($result); `
```

не отправляется в браузере пишет ошибку 500 но подключения есть проверял!
как мне правильно написать php как правильно передаю параметры и получить ответ. Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Огромное спасибо !

---

WSDL выглядит вот так

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://classservice.aaa.bbb.com" name="ClassifiersWS"><types><xsd:schema><xsd:import namespace="http://classservice.aaa.bbb.com/" schemaLocation="http://classifiers.sss.com:80/classservice/service?xsd=1"/></xsd:schema></types><message name="updateData"><part name="parameters" element="tns:updateData"/></message><message name="updateDataResponse"><part name="parameters" element="tns:updateDataResponse"/></message><message name="getVersions"><part name="parameters" element="tns:getVersions"/></message><message name="getVersionsResponse"><part name="parameters" element="tns:getVersionsResponse"/></message><message name="getData"><part name="parameters" element="tns:getData"/></message><message name="getDataResponse"><part name="parameters" element="tns:getDataResponse"/></message><portType name="Service"><operation name="updateData"><input wsam:Action="http://classservice.aaa.bbb.com/Service/updateDataRequest" message="tns:updateData"/><output wsam:Action="http://classservice.aaa.bbb.com/Service/updateDataResponse" message="tns:updateDataResponse"/></operation><operation name="getVersions"><input wsam:Action="http://classservice.aaa.bbb.com/Service/getVersionsRequest" message="tns:getVersions"/><output wsam:Action="http://classservice.aaa.bbb.com/Service/getVersionsResponse" message="tns:getVersionsResponse"/></operation><operation name="getData"><input wsam:Action="http://classservice.aaa.bbb.com/Service/getDataRequest" message="tns:getData"/><output wsam:Action="http://classservice.aaa.bbb.com/Service/getDataResponse" message="tns:getDataResponse"/></operation></portType><binding name="ServicePortBinding" type="tns:Service"><soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/><operation name="updateData"><soap:operation soapAction=""/><input><soap:body use="literal"/></input><output><soap:body use="literal"/></output></operation><operation name="getVersions"><soap:operation soapAction=""/><input><soap:body use="literal"/></input><output><soap:body use="literal"/></output></operation><operation name="getData"><soap:operation soapAction=""/><input><soap:body use="literal"/></input><output><soap:body use="literal"/></output></operation></binding><service name="ClassifiersWS"><port name="ServicePort" binding="tns:ServicePortBinding"><soap:address location="http://classifiers.sss.com:80/classservice/service"/></port></service></definitions>
```

Comment: Если ошибка в браузере - то похоже что вы пытаетесь открыть написаный скрипт через браузер. И этот скрипт падает с ошибкой. Т.е. дело тут не в подключении. Либо ошибка в синтаксисе, либо еще где-то. Так что либо включите вывод ошибок, либо смотрите логи вебсервера или PHP - может быть там есть больше информации.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$request = new stdClass();
$request -> token = '6cc1447c386b4a65b3b980eaf07f7f37f680ec4496b04f1ca2c51';
$request -> tabcode = 'kod';
$request -> tabname = 'text';

$client = new SoapClient (
     "адрес soap?wsdl", 
     array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2)
);

$response = $client->getTicket($request);
```

По идее как то так, но более точно можно по wsdl сказать.